Manga where main character is return to the past by a god wearing a full cloak
So there's a manga stuck in my head and it's split up into 3 pieces:

The main character (MC) got sent back by a god who is wearing a full cloak.
The MC set himself on fire to get free after being imprisoned.
The MC fought the hero.

The MC childhood friend became the saintess if I remember correctly and joined the hero party leaving the MC,the MC wasn't overpowered tho.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

It was a non colored manga

Why was the MC returned to the past? Did they die?

If I'm right the god just return the MC because he wanted to,

Can you elaborate on the 2nd item? How did setting himself on fire free him? Why was he imprisoned? Who imprisoned him - god? someone else? Was this before or after being sent back in time?

After he got send back in time, it was cultist group? or the cities guard, the god only send him back in time, the MC set himself on fire to push another character to be free, and he set himself on fire using a standing torch near him to fight the people who capture him
